# Paragon Backup&Recovery broken incremental backup

Tags: windows, backup, vhd, incremental-backup

In April I made a full backup of my computer using Paragon Backup&Recovery 2014 Free and in June made a incremental backup using same tool. The problem is I didn't check if the backup is ok, and now when I need to recover the files I can only recover files from April. The Paragon does not see the incremental backup and when I try to force open the .vhd file (the incremental archive) program crashes. Running Integrity Validation on the file gives error

```
Operation Failed
Unable to read file
Error source: Hard Disk Manager
Error code 0x11020
```

The question is: Is there any way to either fix this vhd file or to extract some files from it? I do not need all of the files, I just need to get back a few important ones, maybe that would be possible?

And by the way - what other backup tool would you recommend? I don't really like the Paragon tool and since this problem occured now I'd prefer to use another tool next time...

P.S.: In case that helps - in backup root directory there are .pbf, .pfi, .pfm and .0xx files (xx are hex numbers starting from 01 up to 26). All files have the modification date April, except for .pfi which was modified in June. There is also inc directory, in which there are .pfi, .vhd, .vhd.meta and .vhd.ref files, all modified in June.

Comment: What exactly is your question?  The file appears to be corrupt.  If it is then merging a corrupt file with a completed file will just create a corrupted file.

Comment: @Ramhound you're right, there is no point in merging them. I edited the question

Comment: We are not going to be able to recomend other products here at Superuser.  There are already questions that exist on this website that suggest most of the solutions that exist.  You can try and mount the .vhd if it mounts you should be able to extract the files you want provided they are not corrupt.  Its very likely Paragon created the .vhd in such a way that it cannot be mounted in a virtual machine I know Acronis does that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying different programs I managed to successfully recover almost all files from the .vhd file using [Kernel for VHD](http://www.vhdrecoverytool.com/).